# Scrapy IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the results of a game, but there is a game that has the third round and there is a game that does not have, so in the games that do not have the third round the error happens and don't scrape anything.

`IndexError: list index out of range`

Part of code:

```
player1_game1 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(1) td span::text').re('\d')[0]
player2_game1 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(2) td span::text').re('\d')[0]
player1_game2 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(1) td span::text').re('\d')[1]
player2_game2 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(2) td span::text').re('\d')[1]
player1_game3 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(1) td span::text').re('\d')[2]
player2_game3 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(2) td span::text').re('\d')[2]


items['player1_game1'] = player1_game1
items['player2_game1'] = player2_game1
items['player1_game2'] = player1_game2
items['player2_game2'] = player2_game2
items['player1_game3'] = player1_game3
items['player2_game3'] = player2_game3
```

If I don't have the third game, I want to answer nothing, leave it blank, but scrape the rest

error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I resolve this problem and produce the correct results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try...except` block:

```
player1_game1 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(1) td span::text').re('\d')[0]
player2_game1 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(2) td span::text').re('\d')[0]
player1_game2 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(1) td span::text').re('\d')[1]
player2_game2 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(2) td span::text').re('\d')[1]
try:
    player1_game3 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(1) td span::text').re('\d')[2]
    player2_game3 = response.css('tbody tr:nth-child(2) td span::text').re('\d')[2]
except:
    player1_game3 = ""
    player2_game3 = ""
```